# How to retrieve user's phone number from WeChat ID?

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

may I know if there is a way for me to retrieve a phone number from the WeChat MiniProgram sandbox given a WeChat ID?

WeChat documentation states that https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/framework/open-ability/getPhoneNumber.html

> Calling the wx.login API is required before acquiring the user's mobile number linked to Weixin. As the API for acquiring the mobile number can be initiated only by a user’s trigger, click the [button]((button) component to trigger it rather than directly calling the API. Note: **Currently, this API is applicable to non-individual developers, and the Mini Programs which have completed verification (not including overseas entities)**.

I've also inspected the WeChat MiniProgram's network activity and found a "mobile" field but it's encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

"overseas entities" means company or organization not in china.Maybe your company entity can't use this API.

In common when user click the button with attribute of open-type="getPhoneNumber", you can get a code string at callback function.

Posting the code to server.

The server will take the code and token to get the phonebumber from wechat-offical server.The api path is "https://api.weixin.qq.com/wxa/business/getuserphonenumber?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN".

Server docs "https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/api-backend/open-api/phonenumber/phonenumber.getPhoneNumber.html"

It's samiler as the process of get user's base information